# Avatars and names slow to load on mobile chat site

Tags: bug, chat

When I view the mobile variant of the meta chat site, at least half of the avatars don't display and the user's name is simply "loading...". I'm browsing on WiFi so it isn't a bandwidth issue. Often the names will never load.

Note: the missing avatars would be less of a problem if the user's name was still shown.

O/S: Android 4.1.2
Stock browser (Samsung Galaxy Note 2)

Comment: What browser/OS exactly?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Added to question...

Comment: Can you try with some standard browser (Chrome, Firefox) just to eliminate the possibility it's due to the browser you're using?

Comment: @Sha Seems it could be browser related, Chrome is behaving itself.

Comment: Well, good chance that stock browser is simply not supported so the team won't bother fixing this bug. (or just mark this as [meta-tag:status-norepro]) :)